# Sencha Touch autofocus on the textfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, textfield, autofocus

I am unable to make autofocus on the sencha touch textfield.
I have search icon, when I tap on that icon a textfield will appear
Now as soon as it is shown I have to autofocus to that textfield and open the keyboard.
Tried setting listeners to main layout as below

```
listeners : {
            show:function(){

               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('searchlist #searchAreaOverlay')[0].element.down('input').dom.focus();
               setTimeout(function(){Keyboard.hide();Keyboard.show();},500); 
            }

        },
```

Also tried setting painted listener  function of textfield as below

```
{
                xtype : 'textfield',
                itemId : 'searchAreaOverlay',
                id : 'searchAreaOverlay',
                layout : 'fit',
                placeHolder:'Search',
                inputCls:'searchfiledInputCls',

                listeners : {
                    painted: function(){


                         Ext.ComponentQuery.query('searchlist #searchAreaOverlay')[0].element.down('input').dom.focus();

                         setTimeout(Keyboard.show(),100); 
                    },
          }
}
```

Nothing is working.

Comment: Try this this.input().focus();

Comment: But why don't you focus on the textfield while tap event of search icon?

Answer (score 0):

Get reference of that text field and instead of focus use select.

```
this.getSeachField().select();
```